# How to pass a linkedlist from a servlet to another? When I run it says nullpointer exception in listLeagues servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, linked-list

addLeagueServlet.java

```
    String leagueName = request.getParameter("name");
    int leagueYear = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("yearleague"));
    String leagueSeason = request.getParameter("season");

    League league = new League(leagueYear, leagueSeason, leagueName);
    leagueList.add(new League(leagueYear, leagueSeason, leagueName));
    request.setAttribute("leagueList", leagueList);
    out.print("League successfully added!<br>");
    out.print("<a href='Landing.jsp'>Home</a>");
```

listLeagues.java

```
    Iterator iter = ((LinkedList)request.getAttribute("leaguelist")).iterator();
    League league = (League)iter.next();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    out.print(league.getName());
```

So, when I click the List the leagues link in jsp it says null pointer exception. Please tell me how to pass the linkedlist from addleaguelist to listleagues servlet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your code. Added attribute as "leagueList".Trying to retrieve as "leaguelist".